# Java hashmap giving null value even the key and value is not null

Tags: java, null, hashmap

**I have written a code to fetch the value from a table and place it in a map with a key-value pair and return the map.**

```
public Map<String, BigDecimal> fnFetchCartSummary() throws Exception {
        Map<String, BigDecimal> mCartSummaryMap = new HashedMap<String, BigDecimal>();
        int iCartCount = client.getElementCount(CartTotal);
        if (iCartCount > 1) {
            client.ValidateTest(true, "Service charges are getting displayed for Cart. Total entries = " + iCartCount);
            for (int i = 1; i <= iCartCount; i++) {
                String sVariablexpath = sRowKey.replaceAll("<REPLACE>", Integer.toString(i));
                String sVariableName = client.getText(sVariablexpath).replace(":", "");
                String sCharges = RowValue.replaceAll("<REPLACE>", Integer.toString(i));
                double sPrice =Double.parseDouble( client.getText(sCharges).replaceAll("[^0-9.]+", ""));
                BigDecimal bdPrice = new BigDecimal(sPrice);
                mCartSummaryMap.put(sVariableName, bdPrice);
            }
        }
        return mCartSummaryMap;
    }
```

This will return the Map with values like this

```
 {MPVPERTKTF=10, Subtotal=1200, MPVEVTF=15, Total Amount Due=1227, MPV SC001 SPD=2}
```

But when I trying to catch the same map and trying to get the value from it.

```
 Map<String, BigDecimal> mCartValue1 = client.shoppingCart.fnFetchCartSummary();
BigDecimal Subtotal1_1 = mCartValue1.get("Subtotal");
System.out.println(Subtotal1_1);
```

It will show null to every key-value pair like this

null

If anyone comes across the same issue please suggest me a solution.

Comment: It's not possible. I'm sure that you are doing something else.

Comment: Since I have written this code for tool-specific. As java perspective, Could you please elaborate on what the issue here?

Comment: Could you use the debugger to check which elements the map `mCartValue1` contains? (Or simply print it out)

Comment: It looks like you're getting the string values for the map from some external resource (a DOM maybe, or something like that). It's quite possible that the string that shows as "Subtotal" contains some non-visible characters in that version. Print out the length of each key and check it visually against the text to verify that no non-visible characters are included in there.

Comment: Can you do `System.out.println(mCartValue1);` on the line right before `BigDecimal Subtotal1_1 = mCartValue1.get("Subtotal");` and add it to your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with sample demo. It was working fine for me.

1. Please use `HashMap` instead of `HashedMap` or verify what is `HashedMap` implementation.
2. check whether `String sCharges = RowValue.replaceAll("<REPLACE>", Integer.toString(i));` line returning the amount value properly like $1200

```
public class TestHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<String, BigDecimal> mCartValue1 = fnFetchCartSummary();
      BigDecimal Subtotal1_1 = mCartValue1.get("Subtotal");
      System.out.println(Subtotal1_1);
    }


    public static Map<String, BigDecimal> fnFetchCartSummary() {
        Map<String, BigDecimal> mCartSummaryMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();

        //String sCharges = "Rs1200";
        double sPrice =Double.parseDouble( "Rs1200".replaceAll("[^0-9.]+", ""));
        BigDecimal bdPrice = new BigDecimal(sPrice);
        mCartSummaryMap.put("MPVPERTKTF", new BigDecimal(10));
        mCartSummaryMap.put("Subtotal", bdPrice);
        mCartSummaryMap.put("MPVEVTF", new BigDecimal(15));
        mCartSummaryMap.put("Total Amount Due", new BigDecimal(1227));

        return mCartSummaryMap;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found the mistake it was on this line  String sVariableName = client.getText(sVariablexpath).replace(":", ""); it will fetch the key name with spaces and after trimming it its working fine.

Comment: While Debug it it will show properly, But while printing the Map we will get to know about the extra space.